# Reduction of A to B : True or False

Tags: algorithm, computation, p-np

There are two statements:
If a decision problem A is polynomial-time reducible to a decision problem B (i.e., `A≤ pB` ), and B is NP-complete, then A must be NP-complete.

And:

If a decision problem B is polynomial-time reducible to a decision problem A (i.e., `B≤ pA` ), and B is NP-complete, then A must be NP-complete.

Which of the above statements are true?

Can you also give explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the first statement is false because it means that by solving B and then applying some polynomial time algorithm you can solve A but maybe there is another way to solve A that doesn't require solving B and maybe it's only polynomial.

the second statement is true because it means that you can solve B by first solving A then apply some polynomial time algorithm to solve B but B is NP-complete so A has to be NP-complete

Comment: In second case, A can be in NP-Hard also right? Then the statement becomes false.

Comment: @JayPatel in the first statement A maybe NP-hard or maybe not which make the statement False because the first statment says "must be NP-hard" which is not the case but in the second statement A is NP-hard always so it's True

Comment: The second statement is false, because you don't know if A belongs to NP. If so, then A it's NP-complete, otherwise you can't say it!

Comment: Second statement false. It should be Np Hard